# how to change the datetime format in a column in a dataframe with python

Tags: python, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe in python in which there is a column composed by date/time (dd/mm/yyyy hh.mm) and i want to change this format into dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm but i can't find a way!
that is what i have

```
            Data    Ora  Valori
0     01/11/2014  03.00      38
1     01/11/2014  04.00      38
2     01/11/2014  05.00      38
3     01/11/2014  06.00      38
4     01/11/2014  07.00      38
5     01/11/2014  08.00      38
6     01/11/2014  09.00      38
7     01/11/2014  10.00      38
8     01/11/2014  11.00      38
9     01/11/2014  12.00      38
```

and this is what i need:

```
           Data    Ora   Valori
0    01-11-2014  03:00   81
1    01-11-2014  04:00   72
2    01-11-2014  05:00   69
3    01-11-2014  06:00   62
4    01-11-2014  07:00   62
5    01-11-2014  08:00   73
6    01-11-2014  09:00   81
7    01-11-2014  10:00  112
8    01-11-2014  11:00  124
9    01-11-2014  12:00  115
```

Comment: Hi! please have a look at the [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section. SO is not a code factory...

Comment: You can't find something you don't look for. This is an easy solution and there are many answers on how to approach it.

Comment: sorry, but i'm approaching to python from yesterday! i found this
    Datadata= pd.to_datetime(Data1['Data'])
    q=Datadata.astype(str)
    x=Datadata.strptime('%d-%m-%y')
but the error is: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strptime'